# plotting 3D image for the "grazing goat and silo" problem

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am looking for the code to generate a 3D graphic with this area rotated around its PQ-axis:

[image]

The red circle represents a silo centered at point P.  A goat is tethered at point Q on the edge of the silo, with a tether length less than half the circumference of the silo, so that the area the goat is able to roam over is smaller than a circle.

I want to generate a 3D version of this figure, where the 2D figure above is rotated around the PQ axis.  The result should look similar to (but distinctly different from) this

[image]

This example is just two simple spheres, not the more complicated figure I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MMA.SE. Take your equations and read documentation of `ParametricPlot3D` or `SphericalPlot3D`. You are going to be interested in `Opacity` too.

Comment: Obviously I read this and have no clue, that's why i am asking here.

Comment: This is "obvious" only for you because we only see two links in your question.

Comment: See [Goat Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html), [Sphere-Sphere Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html)

Comment: The blue part is not a sphere/circle... and there is no intersection

Comment: I wonder why people are setting this question "on hold" today as "unclear", after it was perfectly answered by Jason yesterday.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you need to do here is to generate a `ParametricPlot` to give the 2D goat/silo problem, and then we can rotate it with `RevolutionPlot3D`.  From reading the page on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html), we can see that we need to make a [circle involute](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleInvolute.html) to describe the portion of the area where the goat's circle is limited by the presence of the silo.  In Cartesian coordinates, this is written

$$ x = r \left( \cos \theta + \theta\sin \theta \right) $$

$$y = r \left( \sin \theta - \theta\cos \theta \right) $$

where $r$ is the radius of the silo and $\theta$ is the angle of rotation.  At the point where $\theta=l/r$, where $l$ is the length of the rope, the goat can then move in an area described by a simple half circle.  So we will run a `ParametricPlot` as a function of `t` where `t` can go from `0` to `l/r`, and we'll go ahead and set `r=0` for simplicity.

First we need the silo,

```
With[{lr = π},
 ParametricPlot[{
   {Cos[2 π t/lr], Sin[2 π t/lr]}
   }
  , {t, 0, lr}]
 ]
```

[image]

Next we bring in the circle involute,

```
With[{lr = 2},
 ParametricPlot[{
   {Cos[2 π t/lr], Sin[2 π t/lr]},
   {Cos[t] + t Sin[t], Sin[t] - t Cos[t]}
   }
  , {t, 0, lr}]
 ]
```

[image]

Now for the portion of the goat's area where it is unimpeded by the silo.  This is a half circle with radius `l` centered at the point `{Cos[l], Sin[l]}` with an initial angle of `l`,

```
With[{lr = 2},
 ParametricPlot[{
   {Cos[2 π t/lr], Sin[2 π t/lr]},
   {Cos[t] + t Sin[t], 
    Sin[t] - t Cos[t]}, {Cos[lr] + 
     lr Sin[lr + (π t)/lr], -lr Cos[lr + (π t)/lr] + Sin[lr]}
   }
  , {t, 0, lr}]
 ]
```

[image]

Finally, to get the last part of the circle, I'll use `ReflectionTransform`

```
With[{lr = 2},
 ParametricPlot[{
   {Cos[2 π t/lr], Sin[2 π t/lr]},
   {Cos[t] + t Sin[t], 
    Sin[t] - t Cos[t]}, {Cos[lr] + 
     lr Sin[lr + (π t)/lr], -lr Cos[lr + (π t)/lr] + 
     Sin[lr]},
   ReflectionTransform[{-Sin[lr], Cos[lr]}][{Cos[t] + t Sin[t], 
     Sin[t] - t Cos[t]}]
   }
  , {t, 0, lr}]
 ]
```

[image]

The next step is to rotate everything so that the tethering point stays fixed, and add a `Point` to show that location, then use `Manipulate` to show the effets of the tether size,

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{silo, circinv1, circinv2, tether, t},
  silo = {Cos[2 π t/l], Sin[2 π t/l]};
  circinv1 = {Cos[t] + t Sin[t], Sin[t] - t Cos[t]};
  circinv2 = ReflectionMatrix[{-Sin[l], Cos[l]}].circinv1;
  tether = {-1 - l Sin[(π t)/l], l Cos[(π t)/l]};
  {circinv1, circinv2} = 
   RotationTransform[π - l] /@ {circinv1, circinv2};
   ParametricPlot[{
    silo,
    tether,
    circinv1,
    circinv2
    },
      {t, 0, l},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Blue, Blue},
   Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{-1, 0}}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-4.5, 2}, {-3.5, 3.5}}]]
  , {{l, .1}, .1, π, .01}]
```

[image]

To turn this into a 3D plot, we will use `RevolutionPlot3D`

```
With[{lr = .5 π},
 RevolutionPlot3D[{
   {Cos[2 π t/lr], Sin[2 π t/lr], 0},
   {Cos[t] + t Sin[t], Sin[t] - t Cos[t], 
    0}, {Cos[lr] + 
     lr Sin[lr + (π t)/(2 lr)], -lr Cos[lr + (π t)/(2 lr)] + 
     Sin[lr], 0}
   }
  , {t, 0, lr}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
  RevolutionAxis -> {Cos[lr], Sin[lr], 0}, 

  PlotRange -> All,
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False]
 ]
```

[image]

Here is an animation for the 3D graphic,

```
Manipulate[
 silo = {Cos[2 π t/l], Sin[2 π t/l]};
 circinv1 = 
  RotationMatrix[π - l].{Cos[t] + t Sin[t], Sin[t] - t Cos[t]};
 tether = {-1 - l Sin[(π t)/(2 l)], l Cos[(π t)/(2 l)]};
 {silo, tether, circinv1} = Join[#, {0}] & /@ {silo, tether, circinv1};
 RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate@{
    silo,
    tether,
    circinv1
    },
     {t, 0, l}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
  RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0},
  PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Opacity[0.5], Blue}, {Opacity[0.5], Blue}},
  PlotRange -> {{-4.5, 2}, {-3.5, 3.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] , {{l, .1}, .1, π, .05}]
```

[image]

### Area (and volume) available for the goat (space goat?) to graze in

Most instances I find online talking about this problem use it as an example for integral calculus - finding the area available for grazing.  You can find the explicit formula for the 2D problem by rewriting the parametric equations to explicitly depend on `l` and `a` (the tether length and the silo radius):

```
{circinv, tether, silo} = {{a (-Cos[l/a - t] + t Sin[l/a - t]), 
    a (t Cos[l/a - t] + Sin[l/a - t])}, 
    {-a - l Sin[(a π t)/(2 l)], l Cos[(a π t)/(2 l)]}, 
    {-a Cos[l/a - t], a Sin[l/a - t]}};

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{tether, circinv, silo} /. {a -> 4, l -> 2}],
 {t, 1/2, 0}, AspectRatio -> .6]
```

[image]

For the area, we find the area of the three regions, add together the circle involute and tether and subtract off the silo, then double it.

```
Integrate[#2 D[#1, t], {t, l/a, 0}] & @@@ {tether, circinv, silo}
Expand[2 (#1 + #2 - #3) & @@ %]
(* {(l^2 π)/4, (a l)/2 + l^3/(6 a) - 
  1/4 a^2 Sin[(2 l)/a], -(1/4) a (-2 l + a Sin[(2 l)/a])} *)

(* l^3/(3 a) + (l^2 π)/2 *)
```

Which matches the formula from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoatProblem.html).  The volume in the 3D case is likewise easily found:

```
Integrate[π #2^2 D[#1, t], {t, l/a, 0}] & @@@ {tether, circinv, 
  silo}
Expand[2 (#1 + #2 - #3) & @@ %] // FullSimplify
(* {(2 l^3 π)/3, 
 1/12 a π (-64 a^2 + 36 l^2 + 63 a^2 Cos[l/a] + a^2 Cos[(3 l)/a]),
  4/3 a^3 π (2 + Cos[l/a]) Sin[l/(2 a)]^4} *)
(* 2/3 π (-18 a^3 + 9 a l^2 + 2 l^3 + 18 a^3 Cos[l/a]) *)
```

$$\frac{2}{3} \pi  \left(18 a^3 \cos \left(\frac{l}{a}\right)-18 a^3+9 a l^2+2 l^3\right)$$

But I haven't seen this anywhere else to check my work :-)

Comment: I wonder what happens to your 2D formula if l > a pi